# Is there a greater than but less than function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code I'm just playing with, As I'm new to python, which is this:

```
a = 0
while a < 10:
    a = a + 1
    print("A is Less than 10")
```

I want to add some more code that says:
If a is more than 10 but less than 20, print this:
I tried:

```
a = 0
while a < 10:
    a = a + 1
    print("A is Less than 10")
while a < 20:
    a = a + 1
    print("A is More than 10, but less than 20.")
```

But all that does is print "A is more than 10, but less than 20"

 Basically, is there a "Less than but greater than" function in python?
I'm running version 3 by the way.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
while 10 < a < 20:
    whatever
```

This doesn't work in most languages, but Python supports it. Note that you should probably be using a `for` loop:

```
for a in range(11, 20):
    whatever
```

or if you just want to test a single number rather than looping, use an `if`:

```
if 10 < a < 20:
    whatever
```

Be careful with the boundary conditions. When your first loop ends, `a` is set to `10`. (In fact, it's already set to 10 when you print the last "less than 10" message.) If you immediately check whether it's greater than 10, you'll find it's not.

Comment: This worked and was exactly what I wanted, thank you! Instead of using a for loop, I just changed my code from "while a < 10:" and used a <= sign instead of just <.

Answer (score 6):

In Python you can even write

```
while 10 < a < 20:
    do_smth()
```